# installed WAMP addons, now wamp won't start

Tags: php, apache-http-server, wamp

I was running Apache 2.2.21 (x64) and php 5.3.10 (x64) but I need to run the x32 versions so I can get ioncube to run.  The support forums on the wamp website I can install any of the addons and it'll automatically install the x32 version.  I did this, told wamp to run apache 2.2.9 and php 5.3.1.  After selecting those versions, the yellow/orange wamp logo appears, but never turns green.

I'm not sure if there's something I have to enable/disable in the firewall or if there's some .ini editing that needs to happen, but I'm at a complete loss.

Anybody experience this before?

UPDATE 1:
I closed WAMP from the task manager, re-opened it, and changed my version back to 2.2.21.  WAMP green-lighted me.  I then changed it back to 2.2.9 and get the yellow light.  Why won't 2.2.9 work?

Comment: I would start by checking check the Apache log file for the exact error.

Comment: The only log in "<DIRECTORY>\apache\Apache2.2.21\logs" is the install log... which has no errors.  Same with Apache2.2.9

Comment: run each app individually from the dos prompt. I have found that the stacks do not report, or suppress, any errors. Starting the apps manually usually show the full errors within the dos box.

Comment: When I dos to the apache2.2.9/bin folder and type in http, i get the following return: "httpd: Syntax error on line 127 of <DIRECTORY>/Apache2.2.9/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load <DIRECTORY>php5.3.10/php5apache2_2.dll into server: %1 not a valid Win32 Application."

Comment: Check in the Windows Event Viewer in the Applications view for error messages from Apache. It could be that you have a problem relating to code compiled with VC6 and VC9 i.e. Apache and PHP must be compiled with the same version of VC++, maybe you have an Apache compiled with VC6 and PHP with VC9 or visa versa. You might be better advised to save all your current wamp stuff uninstall it and download and install a complete 32bit version of Wamp Server.